# Prevent user from navigating the previous page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, href

I have 2 web pages Account.php and Pet_Visit_Hisitory.php
On my Account.php I have a button that has a function

```
window.location.href = 'Pet_Visit_History.php';
```

My Pet_Visit_Hisitory.php has a button function

```
window.location.replace('Account.php');
```

So it went like this:
Homepage.php (Buttonclick)-> Account.php (Buttonclick)-> Pet_Visit_Hisitory.php (Buttonclick)-> Account.php (GoBack) -> Pet_Visit_Hisitory.php

My goal is to prevent the user from going back to Pet_Visit_Hisitory.php
So it goes like this
Homepage.php (Buttonclick)-> Account.php (Buttonclick)-> Pet_Visit_Hisitory.php (Buttonclick)-> Account.php (GoBack) -> Account.php

Comment: You'll have to do something to keep track of where the user can and can't go in the session. You can't prevent the user from telling their browser to load one of your URLs.